# Getting page data using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get page data using cURL and sending variables via POST. Here's the code.

```
$kayako['url'] . '/Core/Default/Login';
$fields = array(
    'username'=>urlencode("username"),
    'password'=>urlencode("password")
);


foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
$fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
}
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,2);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$xml = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

I set see what's coming out (raw) by

```
print_r($xml);
```

However, the page is displaying encoded gibberish to me.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting this helped.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
```